# how to write a script to check all the todos in evernote

Tags: javascript, node.js

So basically you can check the Tanay pratap's video [here](https://youtu.be/yLZazznWoAs?t=4578) [the link will take you to the exact time] where he tells how to accept all of linkedins friend request with a script running on the browser.

My script pasted below can select all the todos but not able to click it

```
document.querySelectorAll("input.list-bullet-todo")
```

above can select all todos but the below code doesn't click it

```
document.querySelectorAll("input.list-bullet-todo").forEach(item =>item.click())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your browser is old and not supporting `NodeList.forEach()`.  Try to use `Array.forEach` instead as follows:

```
var todoList = document.querySelectorAll('input.list-bullet-todo');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(todoList, function (item) {
  item.click();
});
```

Or you can simply extend `NodeList` as follows and then run your code.

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
document.querySelectorAll("input.list-bullet-todo").forEach(item =>item.click())
```